# how to give access to vf page to the secord user

Tags: visualforce, profile, access

I had tired giving access using setup,Develo,Visualforce Page,Security,this way is not working for me. Iam a fresher can u give me an another way to give access.

Comment: That is the only way you can give access. How do you say its not working? What error that user is getting?

Comment: Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Comment: "secord": do you mean second or record?

Comment: This error not necessarily means having problem with VF page, it means the records you are accessing through this VF page is having problems for the second user. First i would check OWD, then roles, then profile and determine whether the user have access to the record or not.

Comment: user getting the records,if i click on record,error encountered.

Comment: On clicking what action is done? Edit, delete? If the user who doing this doesn't have those privileges you would get that error.

Comment: clicking on record just to view the record(detail page)

Comment: and i had ovveridden the view button with a vf page in the admin.

Comment: vf page use custom controller or extension? controller uses with sharing keyword or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38228/discussion-between-vigneshwaran-g-and-sahi).